# Extract the property in MarkLogic java API and get the result

Tags: search, marklogic

I'm new to MarkLogic.

First, I want to use some key-value pairs to do the search, then I got some matched documents.(which I already finished in this part and saved in the SearchHandle results)

Then I want to get the value using specific keys.
So, how can I do another search based on the results?

Or do I need to combine these two steps into one query option?

After I get the final SearchHandle results, how can I get the content?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for the pattern of using SearchHandle:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_64132

That said, SearchHandle tries to provide good summaries of matched documents.

If you want the actual content of documents, you may find it easier and more efficient to query for the documents instead of a SearchHandle:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/bulk#id_37758

After retrieving documents, you can parse them using one of the standard Java libraries such as Jackson for JSON documents or JDOM2 for XML documents.

Whether working with SearchHandle or parsing retrieved documents directly, you can use the values of documents as criteria for new searches.

If you index the documents with TDE, an alternative is to join rows from one view with rows from another view.  The RowManager interface provides a way to use the Optic API to query TDE and range indexes.  See:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/OpticJava

Hoping that prompts some ideas,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to more specific my question. I want to use a key value pairs to find the matched documents, then use a specific property name to get the value from these document. How can I do it, use CombinedQueryDefinition?

Comment: How to use the values of documents as criteria for new searches? could you gives me an example? Like I got the documents from DocumentPage documents = queryMgr.search(querydef, 1); Then how to do the further search with a specific property?

Comment: To match the values of atomic JSON properties, use the RowManager if the documents are indexed by TDE, use a range query if the property has a range index, and use a values query in all other cases.

Comment: After retrieving the JSON documents, you can parse the documents into an in-memory DOM (Document Object Model) on the client using the Jackson library. You can use Jackson to navigate through the DOM tree to the properties of interest and get the values of those properties.  You can then use those values as the criteria for new queries.